# EVENT LOOP is closed discord.py, possible token error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-import

I have looked at the other posts about this issue and didnt find any working solutions. My bot is currently undergoing a development overhaul and I'm moving a lot of my stored data (mod mail bot) into a aiosqlite db. In doing so I have come across this issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 291, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 245, in request     
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Programming/AusSea-Bot/main.py", line 225, in <module>
    client.run(token())
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 295, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001D4CC4B75E0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\L0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

to prevent leaking my token I import another python file `from Token import token` which its sole purpose is to run this line of code `return "token here"`
(full code [here](https://github.com/IsaacWP121/AusSea-Bot/blob/master/main.py))

any clue as to what's going on? has my token been deauthorized or something? (I tried remaking my token and it works for a short time)

Comment: If you do look at the full code expect to find many issues as said I'm in an overhaul stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was completely correct my token was however invalidated by discord and redoing my token fixed it